# Using array for seperate user INPUTS

Tags: c#

Hi i was just wondering if anyone can show me how to use an array with mabye a boolean or something to either end restart last function or start from the very beginning of my Ohm's Law Caculator. Here is my code currently. Im kinda on a time crunch so thank you in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ENGR115_CourseProject_OctTerm
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Console.WriteLine(" Hello my name is Zachari Pryor ");
            Console.WriteLine(" This is the Course Programming Project: Ohm's Law ");
            Console.WriteLine(" The point of the term course project is to use C#");
            Console.WriteLine(" to have user solve Ohm's law using different variables of their choosing.");
            Console.WriteLine(" Press any key to move on");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            enterName();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void enterName()
        {
            Console.Write(" Enter your name: ");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(" Hello it is very nice to meet you " + name);
            Console.WriteLine(" Are you ready to use C# to solve Ohm's Law (y or n) ? ");
            string y = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(" Great!!, well then lets get started.Click enter");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            Equation();
            Console.ReadLine(); 
        }
        static void Equation()
        {
            Console.Write("What would you like to find? V,I, or R:");
            string unitToFind = Console.ReadLine();
        if (unitToFind == "V")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Resistance as a decimal.");
            double R;
            while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out R)) ;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Amperage as a decimal number");
            double I;
            while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out I)) ;
            double V = R * I;
            Console.WriteLine("Voltage is: " + V.ToString() + " Volts");
        }
        else if (unitToFind == "I")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Voltage as a decimal number");
            double V;
            while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out V)) ;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Resistance as a decimal number");
            double R;
            while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out R)) ;
            double I = V / R;
            Console.WriteLine("Amperage is: " + I.ToString() + " Amps");
        }
        else if (unitToFind == "R")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Voltage as a decimal number");
            double V;
            while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out V)) ;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Amperage as a decimal number");
            double I;
            while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out I)) ;
            double R = V / I;
            Console.WriteLine("Resistance is: " + R.ToString() + " Ohms");
        }
        else
        {
          **  Console.WriteLine("You need to enter either V, I or R.  Please run the program again.");
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter 0 to continue working problems");
                Console.WriteLine("1 to quit");
                Console.WriteLine("2 to restart entire program. ");
            }
            int[] actionTake = { 0, 1, 2 };
            {
                Console.Write(actionTake =[1]);
                Equation();
                Console.Write(actionTake[0]);
                Console.ReadLine();
            } 
**
```

I want the code to start back over from the beginning of the the equation(); method if my 0 array is used then if 1 is used to end and close program and 2 i want it to start completley over.
and if possible think of some ways i can use arrays in other areas of the Program.

Comment: Your Array use there makes zero sense. Can you explain WHY you need an array at that particular point? What do the program requirements ACTUALLY SAY?

Comment: i just nee an array used for my project this module week but i didnt want to mess up the previous code I used. I thought that i could use an array to give three different inputs  to either close restart or add a new person to the the post.

Comment: I was asked to add both methods and arrays to my project, this is the only thing i could come up with since I already added my methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
     namespace ENGR115_CourseProject_OctTerm
       {
           internal class Program
          {
        public static int answer { get; set; }
            static void Main(string[] args)
           {
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Console.WriteLine(" Hello my name is Zachari Pryor ");
            Console.WriteLine(" This is the Course Programming Project: Ohm's Law ");
            Console.WriteLine(" The point of the term course project is to use C#");
            Console.WriteLine(" to have user solve Ohm's law using different variables of their choosing.");
            Console.WriteLine(" Press any key to move on");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            enterName();

        } while (answer == 2);
    }
    static void enterName()
    {
        Console.Write(" Enter your name: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(" Hello it is very nice to meet you " + name);
        Console.WriteLine(" Are you ready to use C# to solve Ohm's Law (y or n) ? ");
        string y = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
        Console.WriteLine(" Great!!, well then lets get started.Click enter");

        Console.Clear();
        Equation();

    }
    static void Equation()
    {

        do
        {
            Console.Write("What would you like to find? V,I, or R:");
            string unitToFind = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            if (unitToFind == "V")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the Resistance as a decimal.");
                double R;
                while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out R)) ;
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the Amperage as a decimal number");
                double I;
                while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out I)) ;
                double V = R * I;
                Console.WriteLine("Voltage is: " + V.ToString() + " Volts");
            }
            else if (unitToFind == "I")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the Voltage as a decimal number");
                double V;
                while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out V)) ;
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the Resistance as a decimal number");
                double R;
                while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out R)) ;
                double I = V / R;
                Console.WriteLine("Amperage is: " + I.ToString() + " Amps");
            }
            else if (unitToFind == "R")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the Voltage as a decimal number");
                double V;
                while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out V)) ;
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the Amperage as a decimal number");
                double I;
                while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out I)) ;
                double R = V / I;
                Console.WriteLine("Resistance is: " + R.ToString() + " Ohms");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("You need to enter either V, I or R.  Please run the program again.");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter 0 to continue working problems");
            Console.WriteLine("1 to quit");
            Console.WriteLine("2 to restart entire program. ");
            answer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());



        } while (answer == 0);
    }
}
```

}

Here you go, but i highly recommend you fix some inputs, the possibility for users right now to input wrong data is large.
What your needing is a Do while loop. The Do while loop runs through the entire program 1 time. Afterwards it checks if the condition is true. If it's true, it continues to cycle.

I also agree with comments. I removed a couple, but you use a lot of Console.readLine for nothing? You also have way to many WriteLine. Try to use \n As creates a new line, instead of writing on the same. (Like shift enter in Word).
You could also use A single string/double outside the if parameters for multiple answers.

Answer (score 0):

> i just nee an array used for my project this module week but i didnt
> want to mess up the previous code I used. I thought that i could use
> an array to give three different inputs to either close restart or add
> a new person to the the post.

Here's an example of using an array of strings to display a list of choices to the user in a repeating menu:

```
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    String[] options = {
      "0 - Continue working problems",
      "1 - Quit",
      "2 - Restart entire program"
    };

    int choice;
    do {
      Console.WriteLine("You need to enter either V, I or R.");
      Console.WriteLine("Please run the program again:");
      foreach(String option in options) {
        Console.WriteLine(option);
      }
      Console.Write("Your choice: ");
      String selection = Console.ReadLine();
      if (int.TryParse(selection, out choice)) {
        if (choice<0 || choice >2) {
          Console.WriteLine("Menu choice must be between 0 and 2 inclusive!");
        }
      }
      else {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input!");
        choice = -1;
      }
    } while (choice<0 || choice>2);

    Console.WriteLine("You selected option #" + choice);    
  }
```

You can use logic like this, along with Rojhat Sefdin's example to make a complete program.